# Why does microSD card name keep changing?

Tags: linux, removable-storage

I have a microSD card permanently plugged in to my computer which also contains an internal eMMC (`mmcblk0`).

Sometimes when I turn the computer on it names the microSD card `mmcblk1`, sometimes it names it `mmcblk2` and occasionally it names it `mmcblk3`.

Naming it `mmcblk3` when there's no `mmcblk1` or `mmcblk2` present seems very odd.  No other storage devices are ever attached.

Why does its name randomly change like this?

Comment: The block devices /dev/sdX and /dev/mmcblkN are assigned automatically, and may differ depending of the current state of the computer. In this case it may depend on the card reader's state. User friendly tools should work independently of the current block device. For example, it is a good idea to rely on the UUID or label of the file system(s) in the card. So if you want to mount a partition in the card, I suggest that you use the UUID.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for your comment. I already use `-U <UUID>` to mount. I'm just interested in why the name varies. I don't see how my card reader's state can change. The microSD card is permanently plugged into it.

Comment: It could be anything from the temperature or the voltage of the power network to some flaky performance of a component in the card reader or card itself. (I don't know, but can agree that it is somewhat annoying.)